# adding a pageview count for each profile / account

Tags: php, mysql, view

I'm trying to add a profile viewcount into mysql table and update it with php on refresh page or everytime someone visits their profile.

I'm using this code:

```
    $username = $_GET['user'];
$query = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '". $_SESSION['email'] ."'");
$u = $query->fetch_assoc();
$query = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '". $username ."'");
$r = $query->fetch_assoc();
$profile = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM `users.profiles` WHERE `user_id` = '". $r['id'] ."'");
$p = $profile->fetch_assoc();
$follows = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM `users.follows` WHERE `follow_id` = '". $r['id'] ."'");
$following = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM `users.follows` WHERE `user_id` = '". $u['id'] ."' AND `follow_id` = '". $r['id'] ."'");
```

//this is the count code

```
$viewc = $r['viewcount'] + 1;
$alterview = $connect->query("UPDATE `users.profiles` SET `viewcount` = '". $viewc ."' WHERE `id` = '". $p['id'] ."'");
```

I'm unsure where i'm going wrong, i need it to update +1 count in the viewcount column in the user.profiles table.

Any help will be greatly appreciated guys!

Comment: What is your problem actually? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Undefined index: viewcount in

Which manages to echo out 1 but the above error message appears.

It's setting that to update +1 on refresh

Comment: before you are doing that just do echo `json_decode($r);` and see what you are going to get. And update answer with results.

Comment: JSON_DECODE() EXPECTS PARAMETER 1 TO BE STRING, ARRAY GIVEN IN L78

Comment: use `json_encode($r)`

Comment: On a side note: I seriously hope you've considdered the implications about what you're doing right now. A dedicated MySQL server, which is a server that only works with MySQL and does nothing else, can handle about 250 queries per second. If you start sending out queries all over the place, your website is going to become **very** slow really fast with just a couple of hundred members. And that's if you're lucky.

Comment: {"ID":"2","USERNAME":"OWENDAWSON","EMAIL":"OWEN@.ORG.UK","PASSWORD":"$2Y$10$HNWWQWG5DFCQC0J1RPUVSO9W5AYGNYSRGVPP\/4MA7PX6JL6HVTN1K","NAME":"OWEN DAWSON","COUNTRY":"","SIGNUP_DATE":"2016-08-21"}

Comment: yeah @GoetzPantana pretty much lol

Comment: tried this

    $alterview = $connect->query("UPDATE `users.profiles` WHERE `viewcount` = '". $viewc ." +1 ' WHERE `id` = '". $p['id'] ."'");

@GoetzPantana
& still get the  Undefined index: viewcount in

Answer (score 0):

$viewc = $p['viewcount'] + 1;
    $alterview = $connect->query("UPDATE `users.profiles` SET `viewcount` = '". $viewc ."' WHERE `id` = '". $r['id'] ."'");

this worked, thanks all.